# how to mass Upload user photos to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp, uploading

I'm working on a user management system that uses PHP and mysql.(XAMPP)
it has around 1000+ user records in A table called "users" with "id" as primary key.
one of the columns is "avatar"
I have a folder with 1000+ jpg images. all user images are named by their ids. for example if a user named Jon with id=222 his photo will be 222.jpg

what I want to do is upload all photos to their users using the image name to be put to the correct user id in the table

what's the best approach I can take?
hope its clear and thanks in advance

Comment: Are you saying that you want to put the images _into_ the database? If so - _why_? The file system is usually the much better place to store _files_, and you got all the data you need to "find" the correct image already (i.e., the user id.)

Answer (score 0):

I have some steps that you might do :

1. Upload file as usual, but in this step you must include user id as parameter
2. Query user by id
3. Rename file before save image, example :

   ```
   $user->id . time() . '.' . $file->getClientExtension();
   ```
4. Upload it to folder
5. Save to your table